# Windows Phone 8.1 MediaElement playing audio interupts background audio

Tags: audio, windows-phone-8.1, background-audio

I have an app that plays text to speech at certain events to let the user know what's going on. Due to the target audience of this app, it is likely that the user is playing music in the background. When I call play on the MediaElement the background audio stops and does not resume. In a similar app for Windows Phone 8.0 I handled this by creating a background audio task project, but that behavior is deprecated in 8.1. I've exhausted Bing, Google and the Windows API reference and can't find a solution. This must be possible because I listened to music for hours on Saturday while receiving voice navigation from Here maps and never had to restart the music.

Comment: I've changed my answer to comment, as I don't know the exact one. MediaPlayer and BackgroundPlayer cannot work simultaneously, so it's normal behavior that one is stopping the other. As for HERE maps - I suspect it's using different methods to play audio, not sure whcih ones. To play simultaneously sound you should be able via *DirectSound*, though I haven't tried that yet.

Comment: I understand. I'll see if I can get something working with the MonoGame library.